# Is it better to serve images from Next.js or MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, image, next.js, cdn, vercel

I have **Next.js** web application hosted on **Vercel** with its database on **Mongo Cloud Atlas**. My goal is to assess cost, speed and convenience

**Next.js** can serve static files by placing the files in the same folder as the website itslef. That being said, is it faster to serve images from next or Mongo?

Also, from a cost perspective, mongo is not free.

Comment: Well, Mongo is free, Atlas is not (except M0 tier)

Comment: Yes for the price factor, i guess Vercel wins if you need more than M0 tier. What are your thougts on speed?

Comment: I have write my own experience as an answer. I understand you concern with `M0` Atlas. So that why I am deployed Mongo Community version on my own VPS and decide to manage it. My DB store millions of documents. Top size collection have 12M+ docs. So if Vercel is so good, as it's described, then it's 99% better solution for static content on your site.

Answer (score 2):

I am using the same stack `Next.js` on front-end, and `MongoDB` at backend and this is how I solve the problem:

I store images on CDN node (actually my hosting-provider do it, in my case, my Next.js app doesn't deployed on *Vercel*) and in MongoDB I store http link to a certain image.

Like this one:

```
{
  _id: 123,
  sku: 321,
  media_uri: "https://...."
}
```

Because static assets (images and etc) is stored by Akamai, I always have static links to my `img`. Yes, uri to pictures doesn't change at all, not matter what CDN node will reply it. I know, it could make no sense, I have no clue how does it could be, but it truly works.

That's the result (and as for me, it's blazing fast):
[image]

Less then 1s for 1920x1080 (and sometimes it even 2K resolution pic), and of course they are optimized.

As for the price, my project is on 15+ USD VPS (frontend + backend) so I am not using Atlas (instead I am using community free edition of mongo) and `build` and `deploy` Next.js manually.

Actually most of my costs are back-end generated. Mongo operates with millions of documents in 10 different collection, and deal with heavy `aggregation` queries.

As you my already understood, it's not `localhost/test` type of project.

So my point of view, if Vercel as a platform and it's CDN is so good, as it's described, then it will be much better to store static assets in relative folder with your `src` project and using all the prons of `next.js` with caching and `Vercel deploy`.